# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre “en absoluto” y “para nada”?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, expresiones

Me parece que significan lo mismo pero ¿hay diferentes situaciones donde se usan?

> No me gusta en absoluto.
>
> No me gusta para nada.

¿Estas oraciones significan lo mismo?

Answer (score 2):

El problema de usar "en absoluto" reside en el contexto donde se emplea ya que si va precedida de alguna pregunta, habría que mirar qué es lo que se pregunta y que es lo que se está respondiendo, aunque esto último en ocasiones es incluso ambiguo.

> En absoluto.
>   1 De manera absoluta: sin relación con otra cosa. En sí
>   mismo, por sí mismo, de por sí, de sí, de suyo.
>   2 En frases
>   afirmativas, significa también "completamente, del todo, sin reservas
>   o restricciones": "Estoy decidido en absoluto". Más frecuentemente,
>   tiene sentido negativo, equivaliendo a "de ninguna manera": "¿No te
>   arrepentirás. - En absoluto. No estoy dispuesto a consentirlo en
>   absoluto".